# CssSelector for compound class fails to work, what can be the reason?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

On www.parcelhero.com I'm trying to capture the following 
Webelement:

```
<div class="bs-container btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick show-menu-arrow open" style="top: 315.2px; left: 241px; width: 179px;">
```

using

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("bs-container.btn-group.bootstrap-select.show-tick.show-menu-arrow.open"));
```

But I'm getting

> "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":"bs-container.btn-group.bootstrap-select.show-tick.show-menu-arrow.open"}"

But if I use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='bs-container btn-group bootstrap-select show-tick show-menu-arrow open']"))
```

It works. Why?

Comment: Can you consider updating us actually which element you are trying to locate on the Webpage? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`bs-container` is also a class

```
By.cssSelector("bs-container") // without dot
```

Means you are looking for an element tag `<bs-container>`

```
By.cssSelector(".bs-container") // with dot
```

Means you are looking for an element with class `bs-container`.

Use

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".bs-container.btn-group.bootstrap-select.show-tick.show-menu-arrow.open"));
```

Comment: @user2044296 It might be timing issue, set implicit wait after the driver creation `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.classname(".bs-container"));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try below cssselector

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.bs-container.btn-group.bootstrap-select.show-tick.show-menu-arrow.open"))